# Help in understanding the dynamics of the doubling transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

From the book: 
M.Amigó, Permutation Complexity in Dynamical Systems, Springer Verlag, 2010
 and 
Based on my readings, a concept of symbolic dynamics exists [www2.acqs.org/mathstat/personal_pages/williams/wilshort.pdf](http://www2.acqs.org/mathstat/personal_pages/williams/wilshort.pdf)) which is represented by the dyadic shift map.

It is the study of the coarse-grain partition/ finite discrete representation of an orbit. I am facing problem in understanding part of this concept which says that the Dyadic map represents the dynamics of the symbolic dynamics.

**Question1:** In essence, does this mean that any sequence of 0/1 can be generated or modeled by it? How can Dyadic map be used to generate binary random variables when input is also binary?

**Question2:** Can any chaotic map be used to model/represent binary random variables?

For example: Let a chaotic map $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$ and the starting seed value be x[0] = 0.1. Then, the orbit of `x[0] = 0.1, 0.36, 0.921 6, 0.289 01, 0.821 94, 0.585 42, ...`
which translates into a random sequence = `0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...` if a threshold of 0.5 is used to binarize the real values of the orbit. 
Then there is the dyadic map: $f(x) = 2*x \mod(1)$. When $x$ is a binary bit, then will the output f(x) be binary as well if the dyadic map is the shift map on the space of 0/1 sequences?
How to prove that any chaotic map can be used to represent or model 0/1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You mix the notions strongly. What you mean by **random** is completely unclear.

You can take every binary sequence of 0,1 and act on it by the dyadic map (or by the corresponding shift, to be more precise). If you take a random real number of the interval [0,1], it (its binary representation) gives you a random binary sequence -- you don't have to use dynamics for that.

What you may ask in this context is whether every sequence of outcomes of the Bernoulli experiment (tossing of an independent **random** fair coin) corresponds to some of the trajectories of the **deterministic** dynamical system (shift on the space of binary sequences), and vice versa. Then the answer is "yes" (see the third sentence of my answer).

2) No in any sense. In some cases like $x\to 3 x (\mod 1)$  you work with triadic (ternary) numbers. But there are many examples (and the logistic maps is one of them) where you either can not code the dynamics by a finite alphabet at all, or this coding has bad properties (the conjugacy may not be even Holder continuous. Or may be not continuous at all).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have few questions based on it. Could you please answer? For Question (2) you say that not all maps can be used to model binary valued random variables (r.v) i.e. not all maps can generate binary numbers. How to show or is there any reference? For Question (1) is dyadic map one of the map or is it the only map that can be  used to model binary r.v?  Put in other words by your statement - "If you take a random real number of the interval [0,1], it (its binary representation) gives you a random binary sequence -- you don't have to use dynamics for that" How to prove?

Comment: So, basically how to prove that nonlinear dynamical system operating in chaotic mode generate random numbers - real and binary valued.

Comment: The main qestion is what you mean by random. Techically you consider ANY given sequence (even 1,1,1,1,1) as random. So please specify what you mean - then I will ask you precisely. In general neighbouring entries of an orbit of a continuous map are highly correlated. But the ones distant in time - not necessary.

Comment: By random I mean a random variable that is generated by a random number generator. Ex- bernoulli random variable or uniform random variable. How to show that the shift on the space of binary sequences generates r.v and hence a chaotic map models r.v

Comment: You are asking about pure math or about applications? In the first case if you pick a "uniformly random" initial condition and consider a long trajectory under the action of the doubling map -- statistically it will look like a sequence of samples of the uniform distribution. But there is a dense set of points (periodic ones) whose orbits do not behave like this. In the second case -- technically every software pseudo-random generator is a kind of chaotic map if I remember well.

Comment: Binary sequences (and Benoulli measure on them) and point of a unit interval (with the Lebesgue measure on it) are in (almost) one-to-one correspondence -- so it does not make difference whether you think of a random binary sequence or of a random (in any sense) number from the unit interval. But doubling map is bad here because after around 200 iterations by computer every its orbit falls to $0$ because of special relations between computer representation of numbers and the doubling map (for tripling map it is better).

Comment: Rigorous proofs of pure math statements can be found in any book on ergodic theory. Say, Katok and Hasselblat "Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems".

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they are very useful. I am esp. intrigued by the statement that every pseudo random number generator is a chaotic map. Do you recollect any reference for this as I want a proof for this.

Comment: My impression is that usually those who actually code (or at least those who describe) the algorithms  are often not experts in chaos theory and they do not state is explicitly. You can check many entries here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators, it is easy to see that they correspond to (mulitidmensional) chaotic maps